# Wow.js animated items are sometimes flickering

Tags: javascript, css, animation, frontend, wow.js

I am having some trouble with wow.js. In general, all the animations work just fine, but sometimes the animations just flicker/ glitch instead of properly performing the animation. The only thing that I've found to resolve this issue when it occurs is to restart my pc.

An example of the flickering of the animated elements can be found [here](https://gyazo.com/05cb7af1d19c30962ea6478152886745)

The version of wow.js I am using is v1.1.3 and the version of animate.css is Version 3.7.2 (these were both included in the template I am using)

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this? So far, I've only experienced this on chrome and edge.

**An example of the html in which the wow animation is defined**

```
<div class="row pricing-usp wow fadeUp" data-wow-duration="1.3s" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="usp-bullet usp-bullet-light">
                                        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 pricing-usp-content">
                                    100 producten
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: What animation? We can’t debug something without seeing your code. Please put up a working snippet we can run, thanks.

Comment: I've added a snippet to the question. Initially, I didn't add a snippet because the issue occurs for every wow animation in my project (only sometimes).

Comment: Could you make it a runnable snippet - remember to include any libraries.